Is there a way to DataFrame 'value_count' generated from gaussian mixture model
this shows an output of value_counts generated from a gmm clusters, is there a way to dataframe this data into rows and columns. the 1 represents the total rows that I would wish to df.

my original data frame has 20 rows by 21 columns. I'm trying to get my original data frame but with only 1's as 'GMM_lables' and not 0's.
I'm expecting to dataframe total rows with 1's as 'GMM_lables'


Images of code/data are not acceptable. Please provide a [mre].

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
